# ASP.NET - Ternary operator for different type in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**I want to show "-" in table data if data is zero.**

```
<th>
       @{ 
         int count = 0;
        }
        @(count == 0 ? "-" : count) @*what should I do here??*@
    </th>
```

How will I achieve that??

Comment: And what about this isn't working?

Comment: int - string converting problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to call the `ToString()` method on the `int` type variable `count`

```
<th>
     @{
          int count = 0;
      }
      @(count == 0 ? "-" : count.ToString())
</th>
```

You have to explicitly call the `ToString()` inside the ternary expression. But if you go for a more cleaner - `if-else` approach, you can simply do `@count` and razor will do it(*calling ToString() internally*) for you.

```
<th>
    @if(count!=0)
    {
        @count
    }
    else
    {
        @:-
    }
</th>
```